# VBA code for excel to find quartile one and quartile three my way

Tags: vba, excel

Say I had the data 1,2,3,4,5. I need VBA code or some clever excel work to find the median (3) and then find the medians for either one and two, or four and five depending on the parameter.

If the data was 1,2,3,3,4,5 I would want to find the medians of 1,2,3, and 3,4,5.
But if the data was 1,2,3,4,5 I want it to ignore the 3 and find the medians of the data on either side of the 3. depending on the parameter.

I hope that makes sense, I know some C# but vba and excel are new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was that you could use the quartile, but that doesn't always give the same answer.

If you wanted to ignore the middle value (for an odd number of points) and the middle two values (even number of points) you could try finding the median of a subrange something like this:-

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(A2:A10,1):INDEX(A2:A10,INT((COUNT(A2:A10)-1)/2)))
```

to get the lower median

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(A2:A10,COUNT(A2:A10)-INT((COUNT(A2:A10)-1)/2)+1):INDEX(A2:A10,COUNT(A2:A10)))
```

to get the upper median.

Assumes the data are in ascending order.

To ignore the middle value but include the middle two values:-

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(A2:A10,1):INDEX(A2:A10,INT(COUNT(A2:A10)/2)))
```

and

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(A2:A10,COUNT(A2:A10)-INT(COUNT(A2:A10)/2)+1):INDEX(A2:A10,COUNT(A2:A10)))
```